# viel schön vs viel Schönes

Tags: adjective

After *alles*, *etwas*, *nichts*, *viel* and *wenig* the adjective nouns are in neuter.

Er hat ***nichts Kluges*** gesagt, aber ***etwas klug*** gelöst. (He didn't say anything smart, but he solved something smart). Why is *etwas klug* in lower case?

Another example:
Daran war nicht ***viel schön***.   vs Daran war nicht ***viel Schönes***.

I need help to understand the difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"etwas klug" is in lower case because "klug" is an adverb here, not an adjective. "He solved something in a smart way" would be a better translation.

With regard to your second example, the difference is less obvious. The first one would translate roughly as "Not much was beautiful about it." while the second one would translate roughly as "Not many parts of it were beautiful."

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do you think it would help to add to which verb "klug" is the adverb?

Comment: "The was not much beauty in it " could also go as translation of the first one

Comment: An adverb makes more sense here. In English you'd say "He cleverly solved something." You could solve a clever riddle perhaps, but I have a hard time seeing how that would fit the context.